# What does field `hits.publisher.adsRevenue` mean in GA to BigQuery export schema?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I have recently integrated GA with BigQuery and I was checking consistency of the data. I found most of the metrics in GA correctly matches to data aggregated in BigQuery. However I got stuck to following metrics which description is not even available in `BigQuery Export Schema` https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en.

> 1. `hits.publisher.adsClicked`
> 2. `hits.publisher.adsRevenue` etc.

I looked both GA and BigQuery metrics to guess the mapping of above listed fields but unfortunately I was not able to find any related metrics in GA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are fields for when you use Adsense or AdExchange to serve ads in a website. If you don't use any of these products I think they'll just be blank.

Comment: But there is also fields in BigQuery like `hits.publisher.adxClicks`, `hits.publisher.adxBackfillClicks` and `hits.publisher.dfpClicks` which can be directly map to some metrics in GA.

Comment: a bit late to the party here but... thats because google is messy. They started with Adsense clicks, then they bought doubleclick and integrated with Doubleclick Adx, now there are two variables for two things that are roughly the same but happen in different products. dfp is the publisher side of Doubleclick, adx is the DSP side of Doubleclick